# How do I add a custom style to the IDE menu?

Tags: delphi

I have slightly modified one of the VCL styles provided with Delphi Seattle and saved it with a different .vcf name.  I cannot find a way to add my style to the menu under 'Appearance' in the IDE so that I can select it easily for a project.  The fact that the available styles are grouped as Embarcadero styles implies that creating another group would be supported.

Putting it in the same folder as the others does not make it appear in the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delphi has two folders where you can find style files.

One is placed under base installation path for Delphi/RAD Studio in `\Redist\Styles` (full path example `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\Redist\Styles`) and that is wrong folder to put your styles in.

Another one is in documents folder `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\Styles` and you should use that one for adding your styles into list.

If you have installed Delphi only for current user, then above should be in your users documents folder instead of public one.

Comment: Thanks, now working.  I had moved the file to the latter folder having saved it elsewhere, but (a) I had not remembered to change its internal name, and (b) the editor had actually failed to save the changes I made, so it was identical internally to the original.